# How to read mail from Microsoft Exchange by java on Android

Tags: java, android, email

I have mailbox on Exchange server, connection via SSL/TLS 443 port. How can I read my mail on Android device? I programming on Java in Android Studio. Maybe someone have some experience or code samples?

Comment: check https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/wiki/Getting-Started-Guide

Comment: Thank you. I already try this, doesn't work. Have issue https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/issues/738